# Rewrite host header in HAProxy

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

Trying to rewrite the host header in HAProxy, but can't figure how to do it right.

I need the to rewite to another domain.

Users access the webpage on URI: `site1.dev.example.com` and I need to rewrite the host-header on the backend to `site1.example.local`

It should take all characters until the first dot, and then switch to the local domain.